# Update small tile in window 8.1 store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, live-tile

How can we update small tile (Square 70x70) in windows javascript store app?

The below msdn article says that small tiles only supports badges, but I am not able to figure out exact steps to be performed.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182890.aspx
```

Could anyone please brief the steps required for updating the small tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the small tile only supports badges, you need to make sure to use the BadgeUpdater to issue those rather than the TileUpdater. Check out scenario 4 of the [App tiles and badges sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148). The first step is to call Windows.UI.Notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.createBadgeUpdaterForApplication() (assuming you want the primary tile). This gives you a BadgeUpdater object, and you send the badge XML to its update method.